# asp.net Viewstate and publishing

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I have an asp.net application where users answer question in a quiz.
After clicking on "next" a new question is loaded with an Ajax Postback.

I am using the RadAjaxPanel Telerik Control. I think it uses the UpdatePanel internally.

Will my users have (viewstate) errors if I publish a new version of the application during they are using the site?

Comment: Open inspection tool and check out your Network tab. Are you using an UpdatePanel control or anything that posts the ViewState to server?

Comment: I am using the RadAjaxPanel Telerik Control. I think it uses the UpdatePanel internally.

Comment: that seems like a very broad question, but if you are replacing your config file most likely there will be disruptions as the IIS process will be restarted.